# Use an iPhone as a live system monitor

Tags: iphone, monitoring

A while ago, I was eyeballing the MadCatz STRIKE7 keyboard for a new gaming PC I was building...but as it turns out, its not just sold out, EOL'd but also quite hard to get a hold of. And that is rather unfortunate, because I really liked the idea of using my iPhone as a screen to monitor my PC's information.

There are alternatives by Logitech and Roccat - but they always work best in conjunction with their hardware. I wonder, is there a standalone version of this? A secondary display solution which just gives me some numbers to gawk at, like CPU and GPU temperatures, RAM usage and alike?

Comment: Glances has mobile friendly web pages - https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/ would that meet your monitoring needs?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Pulseway.](https://www.pulseway.com)  Very versatile and supports basically everything.

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.